# How to mock external rest services when writing integration test in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, integration-testing, junit5, spring-integration-dsl

I have a controller from which gateway(Spring integration) is being called. Inside gateway I have several flows where I'm doing some outboundgateway calls. I've written my integration test as below -

```java
@Tag("integrationtest")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = MyWebApplication.class,
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class IntegrationTest {

  @LocalServerPort private int port;

  TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

  @Test
  void testEntireApplication() {

    HttpEntity<LoanProvisionRequest> entity =
        new HttpEntity(TestHelper.generateValidLionRequest(), headers);

    ResponseEntity<LoanProvisionResponse> response =
        testRestTemplate.exchange(
            createURLWithPort("/provision"), HttpMethod.POST, entity, LionResponse.class);

    assertEquals(1, response.getBody().getASMCreditScoreResultCd());
  }

  private String createURLWithPort(String uri) {
    return "http://localhost:" + port + "/lion-service/v1/decisions" + uri;
  }
}
```

It's running the application and proceeding through from controller to the gateway and running the flows as expected. But for the outboundgateway calls it's failing by saying Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://someurl" because it's not able to access the url that's used in the outboundgateway. I want to stub/mock those url somehow. How do I do that?

I tried doing something below in the same class to mock the url -

```java
  MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() throws JsonProcessingException {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).build();
    DecisionResponse decisionResponse = new DecisionResponse();
    creditDecisionResponse.setId("0013478");
    creditDecisionResponse.setResponse(null);
    creditDecisionResponse.setDescription("dummy Response");

    mockServer
        .expect(
            requestTo(
                "http://xyz-some-url:8080/some-other-service/v1/do-decisions/decision"))
        .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
        .andRespond(
            withStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(decisionResponse )));
    mockServer.verify();
  }
```

But still the same error showing and somehow it's not getting called when it's hitting the outboundgateway call inside the gateway flows.

below is the controller code -

```java
  public ResponseEntity<LionResponse> getLionsNames(
      @RequestBody final @Valid LionRequest req,
      BindingResult bindingResult,
      @RequestHeader HttpHeaders httpHeaders)
      throws JsonProcessingException {
      Long dbId = new SequenceGenerator().nextId();

      lionsGateway.processLionRequest(
          MessageBuilder.withPayload(req).build(),
          dbId,
          SourceSystem.ONE.getSourceSystemCode()));
```

below is the gateway -

```java
@MessagingGateway
public interface LoansGateway {

  @Gateway(requestChannel = "flow.input")
  List<Object> processLoanRequest(
      @Payload Message lionRequest,
      @Header("dbID") Long dbID,
      @Header("sourceSystemCode") String sourceSystemCode);
}
```

below is the SpringIntegrationConfiguration class -

```java
 @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return flow ->
        flow.handle(validatorService, "validateRequest")
            .split()
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .scatterGather(
                scatterer ->
                    scatterer
                        .applySequence(true)
                        .recipientFlow(savingLionRequestToTheDB())
                        .recipientFlow(callingANativeMethod())
                        .recipientFlow(callingAExternalService()),
                gatherer -> gatherer.outputProcessor(prepareCDRequest()))
            .gateway(getDecision(), f -> f.errorChannel("lionDecisionErrorChannel"))
            .to(getDataResp());
  }

  public IntegrationFlow callingAExternalService() {
    return flow ->
        flow.handle(
                Http.outboundGateway(externalServiceURL)
                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class))
            .logAndReply("Cd response");
  }
```

.... same way I have other flows that are using outboundgateway but I've not wired the Restemplate instance anywhere.

Comment: Wait, (1.) `setUp` should be probably `@BeforeEach/-All`(junit5) and not `@Test` ...there is a subtle but significant difference!:)

Comment: Another possibility/error source: (2.) Controller/Gateway not using restTemplate !

Comment: 3.: `"http://xyz-some-url...` is wrong... But "still the same error showing and..." hints to 1.!;)

Comment: 1. Continued: you should probably not bind to `new RestTemplate()` ..but to the (correctly!) `@Autowired` one.

Comment: 1...: I would: `bindTo` ..`@BeforeAll` or in test constructor... The "prepare", "expect", "verify": in (individual) `@Test`s.

Comment: The mock must be set up, ready and correctly wired, when you issue your controller (`testRestTemplate.exchange..`) ..after that (line), you can/should "verify" (response&mock).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you do in your mock server setup:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).build();
```

And that's it. The mocked `RestTemplate` instance is not used anywhere.

The `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` has a configuration based on the `RestTemplate`:

```
/**
 * Create a handler that will send requests to the provided URI using a provided RestTemplate.
 * @param uri The URI.
 * @param restTemplate The rest template.
 */
public HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler(String uri, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
```

So, you just need to instrument exactly that `RestTemplate` which you provide for your HTTP outbound gateway.

Right now your mocking code is dead end.

Comment: Artem, I thought internally httpoutboundgateway adapter is using resttemplate to do the http calls. Explicitly I'm not using Resttemplate anywhere in the spring integration flow. I'll add my spring integration flow code for u to understand. Can u pls help me understand how do I mock a httpoutboundgateway then?

Comment: I have updated my post with the full code. Pls explain me how do I wire up this resttemplate?

Comment: That’s correct : it builds an internal `RestTemplate` if you don’t provide external, but you even not trying to instrument it. As I said: your `setUp` method is dead end. You have to declare `RestTemplate` explicitly , inject it into that `Http.outboundGateway` and exactly this one to mock in that setUp. Then `verify()` is also not in the right place: it has to move to specific test method.

Comment: yes Artem I injected the same RestTemplate() in Http.outboundGateway and in the test case and it started working. But when we don't pass restTemplate instance into Http.outboundGateway then how internally it does a http call?

Comment: Using `new RestTemplate()` internally. What is wrong with that? By default `RestTemplate` is going to make a real HTTP connection. Your idea is to mock it, so you need instrument with a mock a `RestTemplate` used in the `Http.outboundGateway` before sending messages to the input channel.

Comment: before I was doing like this - Http.outboundGateway(otherServiceURL) but now just to write the test case in the main config file I need to write like this - Http.outboundGateway(creditDecisionServiceURL, restTemplateConfig.restTemplate()). So I was asking if it uses RestTemplate internally then why I need to pass the RestTemplate to the http.oudboundgateway ? I have no issues with it it's just that I don't like the fact that to cater the test case I need to change the existing codebase.

Comment: Technically it is better to always inject a predefined `RestTemplate`. For your use-case it even might be better to reply on the one provided from Spring Boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#io.rest-client.resttemplate. The option without is just for convenience to code a quick program.